# Random not so random - depend on previous call so it seems

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

In vb.net I am using this function to get random numbers:

```
  Private Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
  End Function
```

I am calling the GetRandom function several times from another function which looks like this (simplified):

```
Public Sub GetRandomPerson() 
  Dim Gender as integer
  Dim Zip as integer

  Gender = GetRandom(1,3)
  Zip = GetRandom(10000, 99999)

  ' Here I save the random person to DB
End Sub
```

And then I have this

```
For i As Integer = 1 to 10000
  GetRandomPerson()
Next
```

My problem is that there seems to be a dependency on calls to GetRandom, it seems that if Gender is 1 then Zip will never be higher than a certain value (around 5000) and if Gender is 2 then Zip will always be higher than a certain value (around 5000).

Why is that, what am I missing?

Comment: Try it by taking the `Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()` out of the function

Comment: @J. Steen After reading the other answer I agree and it gave me the solution / should I delete my question?

Comment: @Muleskinner If you feel it doesn't contribute to the stackoverflow community, delete it. If you feel there's extra information that's invaluable, don't delete it. =)

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating `Random` on *every* call. This is why you are getting the results you are seeing:

```
Dim Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
```

`Random` uses a seed based on the current time to generate a pseudo random sequence (which, if has the *same* seed, will generate the *same* sequence) - if called in a loop as you do, there can be 0 change in the seed, generating the same values over and over.

Move the instance outside of the function, so you only ever use a single instance of the generator.

I suggest reading this article by Jon Skeet about [Random](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx).